# Excel VBA - loop over files in multiple folders, copy range, paste in this workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 28 spreadsheets, all in different folders. Each spreadsheet has a flat list I need to pull into one document and update it every 4 weeks. I am struggling to get my head around how to code fulfilling the following requirements;

1. I want to loop over a specific sheet ("TRIMP Load Data NEW") in multiple files, all of which have different path's (no its not possible to put them in one folder)
2. copy this range "Planned Load"
3. paste all data from all files into the 1st sheet of the active workbook
4. the next time I do it I want the data to be overwritten and replaced

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Pete, when posting to StackOverflow it is best practice to post 1 specific question at a time, with any code you may have tried that isn't working out for you. From your question it doesn't seem like you know how to accomplish **any** of these tasks, and should therefore spend time learning one before moving onto the next.

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted in your previous question? As I said there, you should try some code and post back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the source folders and files as a path in the cells down column A in a spreadsheet - perhaps the second one in your currently open file?. Then your code should :

```
Sub Example
'set a pointer to A1 in second page
Dim r as range
set r = thisworkbook.worksheets(2).range("a1")
'loop down column A until you reach an empty cell
do until r = ""
'for each cell, open the workbook identified, 
dim wb as workbook
set wb  = workbooks.open(r,False,True) 'open workbooks, don't update links, read only
 'grab your range
 dim source as range
 set source = wb.worksheets("TRIMP Load Data NEW").Range("Planned Load")
 'copy it to your target at the next blank row
  source.copy 'copy data
   thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("a" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0).pastespecial xlpastevalues  'paste values
 Application.cutcopymode = false 'prevent prompt after paste     
 'and close the source file
  wb.close false      
  'move down to next row in your list
  set r = r.offset(1,0)
  'and ...

  loop
 end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and code. Really helpful. I keep getting an error message 'Run Time Error 6: Overflow. I click debug and ' source.copy thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("a" & cells.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)' is the issue

Comment: Sorry - should be rows.count not cells.count in that line - brain clearly not engaged at that point

Comment: Thats working great, thanks! Just two more questions... 1) each workbook is asking me to update links which I have to click 'update' and then it tells me it can't update links so I have to click 'continue'. It asks me this for every file it opens. Is there anyway of getting the macro to do this for me? no worries if not :). Second Q is can I paste values and its currently pasting the formulas. Thanks

Comment: Thats working perfectly. Its not asking if I want to keep the data on the clipboard to be used later to which I need to click 'no' for every file.